# How to prevent multiple initialization of dynamic library

Tags: python, c, openssl, initialization, python-import

I am working on Python version 2.7.
I have a module extension for Python written in C.
The module initialization function `PyMODINIT_FUNC initmymodule` contains some code for initializing OpenSSL library. My module built as shared library and loading via `imp.load_dynamic`

This module may loading many times and I can't control it. Django and python doing that. And when it loading twice then `OPENSSL_config` function calling twice too. And it leading to process crash.

I can't control it from C-code, I can't control it from Python-code.

Here look at the docs
http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/imp.html
It says:

> imp.load_dynamic Load and initialize a module implemented as a
>   dynamically loadable shared library and return its module object. **If
>   the module was already initialized, it will be initialized again**.

Nice.

I found that the similar problem was solved in Python version 3.4
http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ad51ed93377c/Python/import.c#l459

> Modules which do support multiple initialization set their m_size
>   field to a non-negative number (indicating the size of the
>   module-specific state). They are still recorded in the extensions
>   dictionary, to avoid loading shared libraries twice.

But what shall I do in Python 2.7?

Comment: Kudos for digging around in the source.  +1 to you

Comment: Complain to the OpenSSL developers. This is a serious bug in their library.

Comment: The asterik package did it by wrapping the initialization call with their own call that they would [dynamically remap](https://reviewboard.asterisk.org/r/1006/).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe to do workaround by registering own custom import hook where you could control the case which causes you problem (prevent double initialization). Some references for writing custom import hooks:

- Python import hooks [article](http://orestis.gr/blog/2008/12/20/python-import-hooks/)
- [PEP-302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) New Import Hooks - python 2.3+
- create and register custom import/reload functions - example of implementation in project [lazy_reload](https://github.com/boostpro/lazy_reload/blob/master/lazy_reload.py)

This is *hackish* solution, so I suggest extra caution if this is to be used in production systems.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of my problem. It happens because my django application uses driver to connect PostgreSQL and this driver loads OpenSSL library. It leads to conflict just as [user315052](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315052/user315052) showed in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652512/how-to-prevent-multiple-initialization-of-dynamic-library#comment23964046_16652512)

I think I have to take out all crypto-functionality of my application to a separate process.